# Options for running -O flag

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I've been having trouble finding alternative ways in which Python can be ran with the -O flag. Are there any other ways besides including in a script that calls the IDLE and .py file?

Is a script necessary? Can it be included in the .py file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an environment variable. From the [`-O` switch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-O):

> Turn on basic optimizations. This changes the filename extension for compiled (bytecode) files from `.pyc` to `.pyo`. **See also [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE).**

Bold emphasis mine. The linked `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable documentation states:

> If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to specifying the `-O` option. If set to an integer, it is equivalent to specifying `-O` multiple times.

There are no other methods of enabling this mode, so yes, you need to either invoke Python with the command line switch from another script, or use *something* to set the environment variable before running Python.

You can't enable it from the `.py` file as it needs to be enabled *before* the Python code is parsed and compiled.

Note that the only thing `-O` does is omit `assert` statements from the code being run, and to set the [`__debug__` global constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=__debug__#__debug__) to `False` (it is set to `True` otherwise). If `-O` was specified twice, docstrings are removed from the bytecode too, giving you *slightly* smaller bytecode files.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - is there a more beginner friendly resource on how to use environment variables than the official documentation? It reads almost like gibberish to a beginner like me.

Comment: What OS are you using? There are loads of resources on environment variables for any OS you care about.

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I don't use Windows myself, surely there are loads of tutorials that explain environment variables on Windows?